# printing list elements side by side -- file operations

Tags: python, list, file, while-loop, append

```
    j=0
    while j<5:
       random_lines=random.choice(men_heroes_lines)
       element=(random_lines.split(":")[0:1])
       random_lines_women=random.choice(women_heroes_lines)
       element_women=(random_lines_women.strip("\n").split(":")[0:1])

       print element
       print element_women
       j=j+1
```

hey guys here is my question.. i have two txt files which contains men and women names..
as:

```
manname1: a b c d
manname2: x y z e
...
```

i managed stripping to ":" but i can't write them side by side in a list..

```
expected output is=
["manname1","manname2","manname3"...]
however it is:
["manname1"]
["manname2"]
["manname3"]
```

how can i do it as in the expected output.. thanx in advance :)

this is my sample file..

```
 Ant Man: a, b
 Frodo: x,y
 Star : s, d
 Thor: r, t
 Spy: p,u
```

ant man,frodo,star... is the men mame.. and what i want to append a list..

Comment: Please provide a runnable code snippet and examples of your two input files.

Comment: i updated my question..thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe create another list for example names and instead of printing the element on each iteration append it to this list. And then print the list after the loop is over.

```
j=0
women_names = []
while j < 5:
    . . .
    women_names.append(element_women)
    j += 1
print women_names
```

Comment: Also you can make `j = j+1` to `j += 1`.

Answer (score 1):

As a general approach, instead of `print` use

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write(element)
sys.stdout.write(element_women)
```

which does not add newlines at the end.

In Python 3 note

```
print(element, end="")
print(element_women, end="")
```

In case the input does not show immediately (large buffer), consider respectively

```
sys.stdout.flush()
```

and

```
print(element, end="", flush=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use ','

```
print element,
print element_women
```

example:

```
print 'a',
print 'b'
output
a b
```